# Why are the by-hash directories on ubuntu mirrors not hard linked?

Tags: rsync, mirrors, hard-link

I noticed that the files in the `by-hash` directories are not hardlinked to the actual files, as I would have expected. This means that any mirror downloads consume double the time and bandwidth for the `dists` directories.

Is this a problem or an actual design decision?

To demonstrate, I can rsync down a very small directory from the official mirror. You'll notice that the timestamps are actually different, so it is not a matter of hard links not being replicated:

```
+ rm -rf /tmp/test
+ rsync -aAH --delete rsync://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic-proposed/restricted/source/ /tmp/test/
+ echo 0
0
+ find /tmp/test/ -type f -exec ls -igG '{}' +
51 -rw-r--r-- 1  64 May 18 01:30 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/1ecf8ede6a1ae61b641204572f1da419db0786316399292b17e653658e90f36e
52 -rw-r--r-- 1 112 May  2 03:56 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/c2250852d322551048ac95dfcaa941a5dd4ebb29dbb64e8ccb101c78b62b4217
53 -rw-r--r-- 1  40 May 18 01:30 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/e7ab72b8f37c7c9c9f6386fb8e3dfa40bf6fe4b67876703c5927e47cb8664ce4
47 -rw-r--r-- 1 112 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Release
48 -rw-r--r-- 1  40 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Sources.gz
50 -rw-r--r-- 1  64 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Sources.xz
+ hardlink -t /tmp/test
Mode:     real
Files:    6
Linked:   3 files
Compared: 0 xattrs
Compared: 3 files
Saved:    216 bytes
Duration: 0.00 seconds
+ find /tmp/test/ -type f -exec ls -igG '{}' +
50 -rw-r--r-- 2  64 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/1ecf8ede6a1ae61b641204572f1da419db0786316399292b17e653658e90f36e
47 -rw-r--r-- 2 112 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/c2250852d322551048ac95dfcaa941a5dd4ebb29dbb64e8ccb101c78b62b4217
48 -rw-r--r-- 2  40 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/by-hash/SHA256/e7ab72b8f37c7c9c9f6386fb8e3dfa40bf6fe4b67876703c5927e47cb8664ce4
47 -rw-r--r-- 2 112 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Release
48 -rw-r--r-- 2  40 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Sources.gz
50 -rw-r--r-- 2  64 Oct 15 11:35 /tmp/test/Sources.xz
```

Comment: Is it possible that the main archive.ubuntu.com uses links, but the mirror you're using lost that information because of whichever syncing method it uses?

Comment: @muru updating my question clarifying why I don't think this is a mirror issue: 1) did test against main mirror and 2) the timestamps are off anyway

Comment: Your update didn't clarify anything because 1) I said the `archive.ubuntu.com` repository, the source of mirrors, not a mirror, and 2) they could use symbolic links, in which case the timestamps would be of the links, not the target, but save space anyway.